# How should I fill in the printf statements in this code?

Tags: if-statement, arguments, printf, atoi

I have an assignment where we've been asked to analyze the code below and fill in what the printf staments should be. I'm kind of stuck, so any recommendations would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int maximum(int x, int y)
{
if(x > y)
{
    return x;
}

if(x < y)
{
    return y;
}
return 0;
}

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
int first;
int second;
int data;

if( argc != 3) {
    printf("
    retunr 0;
}

first = atoi(argv[1]);
second = atoi(argv[2]);

data = maximum(first,second);

if(data)
{
    printf("
}
else
{
    printf("
}
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print `data` value

```
printf("%d", data);
```

If you want to print any random `string` value

```
printf("Print whatever you want here");
```